# Visual C++ Volatile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, volatile

The MSDN docs for "volatile" in Visual C++ indicate that writes have "release semantics" and that reads have "acquire semantics", in addition to ensuring that reads always read from memory and that writes always write accordingly.

The C spec for "volatile" includes the second part (don't do crazy optimizations), but not the first part (a memory fence).

Is there any way in Visual C++ to get the "C" volatile behaviour only, without the memory fence?

I want to force a variable to always be on the stack, in a fixed spot, but I don't want to take the overhead of a memory fence on every assignment to it.

Is there any easy way to do that with Visual C++ source?

Comment: The first part is not Standard C++ behaviour, I think. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: "I want to force a variable to always be on the stack, in a fixed spot" and how would `volatile` help with that? FWIW, variables are *always* in a fixed spot. @Nawaz: no, the first part is not standard.

Comment: @Fernades Local variables are NOT always in a fixed spot. Local variables can be eliminated, or their address on the stack can be in different spots depending on where the PC is. The optimizer can do lots of crazy stuff. I want to suppress those optimizations. The way to do that is to use "volatile". However, I don't want the not-mandated-by-the-standard memory fence that Visual C++ throws in.

Comment: edited to (hopefully) make it clear that this is MS-specific behavior.  In fact I think it only applies to Visual C++ 2005 and later.

Comment: @ScottWisniewski: It's more likely to be on the stack at times, and in registers at times, rather than two different locations on the stack.  But you definitely have a point.

Comment: Even when marked with volatile the address of a local variable can change with each invocation unless you make it static. Volatile does not fix addresses.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Seems like he's talking about during a single invocation.

Comment: @Fernades I'm going to have a stopped thread, and a shadow stack, with precise information about all pointers (or all the one's I care about) on the thread's stack. I can do this because I'm generating the C++ source (I know generating C++ source may suck, but I'm stuck with it for now). I want to make sure the values read by the generated machine code will be read from the stack slots, because I'm going to fixup the pointers as part of a compacting memory operation. I don't want to force a memory fence on normal reads though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way in Visual C++ to get the "C" volatile behaviour only, without the memory fence?

On x86 there are no memory fences created at the assembly level on reads and writes to a `volatile` memory location since on that platform every load has acquire semantics, and every store has release semantics.  Therefore for MSVC on x86, the `volatile` directive simply directs the compiler to prevent the reordering of loads and stores depending on if you are writing or reading from the memory location that was marked `volatile`.

You would only incur the "penalty" of a memory fence on the IA64 architecture, since there the memory ordering model of the platform does not ensure acquire and release semantics for loads and stores.

Keep in mind this behavior is MSVC-specific, and is not a standardized semantic of `volatile`.

**Update**: According to @ildjarn you would also see a memory fence on ARM with Windows 8 since that platform also has a weakly ordered memory-consistency model like IA64.

Comment: The penalty applies to ARM as well.

Comment: Does MSVC work on ARM? ... I didn't know you could run Windows programs on ARM ...

Comment: ARM is a primary platform for Windows 8, so MSVC11 supports ARM as a primary architecture as well.

Comment: Thanks! IA64 isn't a big deal. On Arm, is it possible to suppress the memory fence?

Comment: Nobody remembers Windows Mobile anymore :)